# Finding the difference between two sets of data using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have two array, each consisting of hundreds of different values, lets say,

list1 = [23.13, 89.50, 12.99, 40.89,...]

list2 = [45.21, 2.02, 79.89, 20.30, ....]

I have a separate array that indicates the indices of the entries I want to compare from each array (a 0 indicates the first entry in both arrays, 434 indicates the 435th entry and so on). Lets call this array

indx = [0, 12, 304, ...]

My goal is to take the entries from both lists that have the index listed in indx, subtract the values, and store them in another array. I would like to use Pandas as most of my code to get to this point has used pandas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
list1 = np.array([23.13, 89.50, 12.99, 40.89])
list2 = np.array([45.21, 2.02 , 79.89, 20.30])

indx = [0, 2, 3]
```

Then simply

```
>>> list1[indx] - list2[indx]
array([-22.08, -66.9 ,  20.59])
```

Similarly, if you have `pd.Series` instead of `np.array`,

```
pd.Series(list1)[indx] - pd.Series(list2)[indx]

0   -22.08
2   -66.90
3    20.59
dtype: float64
```

For asymmetric lengths,

```
nindx = indx[indx < min(map(len, [list1, list2]))]
>>> list1[nindx] - list2[nindx]
```

Comment: Ah I see. My only issue (as I should have mentioned, sorry) is that list1 and list2 are not the same length and when I try this approach I get an error.

Comment: Then you have indexes in your `idx` that are greater than one of the lists. How would you like to proceed when this happens?

Comment: I am not sure. I guess this may be the root cause of my issue. Is there a way to just ignore the extra entries in the indx array?